# Java parsing text file and preserving line breaks?

Tags: java, regex, parsing, file

I have been researching how to do this and becoming a bit confused, I have tried so far with Scanner but that does not seem to preserve line breaks and I can't figure out how to make it determine if a line is a line break. I would appreciate if anyone has any advice. I have been using the Scanner class as below but am not sure how to even check if the line is a new line. Thanks

```
    for (String fileName : f.list()) {

            fileCount++;

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(f, fileName));
            int count = 0;
            String outputFileText = "";

            //System.out.println(fileCount);

            String text="";
            while (sc.hasNext()) {

                String line = sc.nextLine();
            }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by check if the line is a new line?  Scanner.nextLine() already breaks up the file into lines for you so all you have to do is scan each invdividual line you get to find values, etc.

Comment: If you are using a BufferedWriter, you could also use the .newline method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199216/strings-written-to-file-do-not-preserve-line-breaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just trying to read the file, I would suggesting using [`LineNumberReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) instead.

```
LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f));
String line = "";
while(line != null){
    line = lnr.readLine();
    if(line==null){break;}
    /* do stuff */
}
```

Comment: I need to read it line by line and then I am doing some things with the line to check for values (using regex).. thanks I will take a look at `LineNumberReader`

Comment: As Chuck notes, the superclass `BufferedReader` provides similar functionality. (I just like knowing what line I'm on if I have to craft an error message.)

Comment: so if it picks up a newline character (for example `\n` ) I could just pass that through to the output string I am creating?

Comment: The return value of `readLine()` shouldn't have any any newlines in it. (That is, `\r\n`, `\n`, or `\r`.) If `readline() == ""` then you know it saw a line with *only* a newline at the end and no other content. If you're trying to test for lines that contain `\r\n` (from windows) versus `\n` (unix style) then this won't help you because it treats them all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Java's Scanner class already splits it into lines for you, even if the line is an empty String.  You just have to scan through the lines again to get your values:

```
Scanner lineScanner;
while(sc.hasNext())
{
    String nextInputLine = sc.nextLine();

    lineScanner = new Scanner(nextInputLine);

    while(lineScanner.hasNext())
    {
        //read the values
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [BufferedReader#readLine](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29).

Comment: The Javadoc for BufferedReader#readLine, specially indicates that newline chars are removed.